# terminal error in between connecting SSL certificate and private key to set up a secure connection:

Tags: objective-c, openssl, apple-push-notifications

i am trying to do push notification in my app and following this link
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

my system has been successfully connected with telnet but when i enter the query for connecting ssl certificate and private key then found a error

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-dev-cert.pem -key apns-dev-key.pem
unable to load client certificate private key file
1301:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

any one can tell me what type of error and what's the solution of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following command is good enough to verify the key/cert:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert push_development.pem
```

The key part is to select both **certificate** and **private key** when exporting the .p12 from Keychain Access (you will be asked for 3 passwords, one for the .p12, one for the cert, one for the private key).

To convert .p12 to .pem, follow the instruction from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW6):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out CertificateName.pem -nodes
```

Comment: Does not help still giving "unable to load client certificate private key file". `openssl s_client -connect api.development.push.apple.com:443 -cert my.pem`

Answer (score 15):

At first i was facing this problem too.

We have two files

1) one is `aps_development.cer` from apple
2) Another 1 is from the `keychain access` with the common name that we just created.

After that, both convert it to `.pem` files. 
For example, `cert.pem` and `key.pem`. 
After that combine this two files using below command

```
cat cert.pem key.pem > ck.pem
```

At first I openssl using below command.

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
    -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
```

Which returns me the error you mentioned.
After that I try using

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
    -cert cert.pem -key ck.pem
```

Then its working already. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the same things but the problem is still there. Any more suggestions? thx

Comment: I tried the proposed solution but the error is still there. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue while I was generating a PEM file for Enterprise Distribution, but i figured out later that I generated a p12 file against the ***iPhone Distribution Certificate*** key though i should had generated the p12 against ***Apple Production iOS Push Servies*** key. Hope this may resolve the issue if any one had used the Distribution key.

Answer (score 3):

Hello Please follow below commands.
step1
`openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out developer_key.pem -in developer_key.p12`

Note: just drag the file path on terminal...

step2
`openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out apns_key.pem -in apns_key.p12`

step3 
`openssl pkcs12 -in developer_key.p12 -out developer_key.pem -nodes -clcerts`

step4
`openssl pkcs12 -in apns_key.p12 -out apns_key.pem -nodes -clcerts`

step 5
`cat apns_key.pem developer_ket.pem >developer.pem`

DO the same step For Distribution certificates

After creating developer.pem and distribution.pem

Please verify both file in to below commands.

Step6
`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert developer.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile "Entrust.net.Certification Authority (2048).pem`

Answer (score 2):

A Notice is **Pass Phrase must longer than 3 characters.**

I have just fixed with pass Phrase is **1234** :D